# Как решить проблему с синтаксисом sql запроса insert

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**Ошибка:**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "order"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO sheet (id, order, cost, delivery_time) VALUES (1...
```

**Мой запрос:**

```
INSERT INTO sheet (id, order, cost, delivery_time) VALUES (1, '1231231', 123213, 2022-07-26);
```

**Моя таблица в SQL:**

```
 id | order | cost | delivery_time 
----+-------+------+---------------
(0 rows)
```

**Типы данных колон:**

```
Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), 
Column('order', String(255), unique=True), 
Column('cost', Integer),
Column('delivery_time', Date)
```

Comment: `order` — ключевое слово sql. лучше не использовать ключевые слова, а если всё-таки используете, то надо его экранировать. обратными слэшами, скорее всего.

Answer (score 1):

`order` ключевое слово в postgres. Если используете его как имя колонки или таблицы нужно брать в двойные кавычки:

```
INSERT INTO sheet (id, "order", cost, delivery_time) VALUES (1, '1231231', 123213, 2022-07-26);
```

Не забудте правильно кавычки экранировать, если запрос у вас в питон строке ограниченой двойными кавычками. Или ограничивайте тройными кавычками:

```
myquery = """INSERT INTO sheet (id, "order", cost, delivery_time) VALUES (1, '1231231', 123213, 2022-07-26);"""
```

или экранируйте обратным слешем:

```
myquery = "INSERT INTO sheet (id, \"order\", cost, delivery_time) VALUES (1, '1231231', 123213, 2022-07-26);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что скорее всего слово "order" забронированное в sql.